# How to know if the username is already in the database in PHP using Prepared Statements?

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, phpmyadmin, prepared-statement

Here is My code :

```
$sql = "SELECT name FROM trainee WHERE username=?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
    header("Location: ../Sign_Up.php?error=SQL_Error");
    exit();
}else{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $resultCheck=mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    if($resultCheck>0){
        header("Location : ../Sign_Up.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$Name);
    }else{
               //Some code
    }
}
```

the Error :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
> Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1h PHP/8.0.0 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: Did you check the error log like it suggested?

Comment: how can i do it ? please tell me

Comment: I don't know anything more than what's in the linked question.

Comment: the linked question doesnt solve my problem..any way thanks sir.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any more than that.

Comment: no problem sir.